# How evaluate and die model works?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I have a few doubts about how the evaluate-and-die model works. First of all, how can this model control thread granularity ?

My second doubt is about how evaluate-and-die flow behaves, for example, if a have a function like this:

```
map (spark g) [1..10] 
  where 
      spark f x = x `par` f x 
      g x = x^x
```

The flow of the evaluate-and-die model would be unique for this function execution ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Perhaps it will help anyway to consider that the first application, `spark g 1` is simply `1 \`par\` 1^1`.

Comment: I am trying to construct a diagram to see how this model works. I am considering that this function will spark x and evaluate f x, but the main thread will probably evaluate x first and the spark will be fizzled. However, I am not sure if this is the only way that this function will behave considering the evaluate and die model.

Comment: I do not know about evaluate-and-die. However, using `map` and `par` in this way seems to use at most two cores at a time. When an element of the list is forced in the main thread, a single spark is created. Then, assuming `g` strict, the main thread will not start evaluating another list element until the spark has completed. So, a second spark will not be created until the first spark has completed. Is this what you want to achieve?